# How to truncate text in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is there a way that I could limit the length of the string to a number characters?
for e.g: I have to limit a title length to 20 `{{ data.title }}`.

Is there any pipe or filter to limit the length?

Answer (score 576):

> Two way to truncate text into angular.

```
let str = 'How to truncate text in angular';
```

**1. Solution**

```
  {{str | slice:0:6}}
```

*Output:*

```
   how to
```

**If you want to append any text after slice string like**

```
   {{ (str.length>6)? (str | slice:0:6)+'...':(str) }}
```

*Output:*

```
 how to...
```

**2. Solution(Create custom pipe)**

> if you want to create custom truncate pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'truncate'
})

export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
    const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 20;
    const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';
    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
   }
}
```

In Markup

```
{{ str | truncate:[20] }} // or 
{{ str | truncate:[20, '...'] }} // or
```

Don't forget to add a module entry.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TruncatePipe
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Which solution is good in performance. Solution 1 or solution 2. I think solution 1 is good in performance.

Comment: you might wanna add a null check to the return statement, in my case I was passing in an empty string and it was causing my app to crash.

`return value && value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;`

Comment: @ketan: sir i have tried both solution its working perfectly but my scenario is different we have initialy show 50 characheter and more text will be show after click read more link so tell me its possible with above?

Comment: In solution 2, `transform(value: string, args: string[]): string` should be `transform(value: string, args: any[]): string` since the first argument given to the pipe is a number.

Comment: Hi Ketan, can you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040964/how-to-concat-a-string-after-using-slice-pipe

Comment: Liked the custom one, here is my better (IMHO) implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70189399/11347983

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. And I have improved the second solution a little: `transform(value: string, args?: [number, string?]): string {
    const limit = args ? args[0] : 20;
    const trail = args && args[1] ? args[1] : '...';
    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
   }
}` .

Answer (score 117):

Truncate Pipe with *optional* params:

- **limit** - string max length
- **completeWords** - Flag to truncate at the nearest complete word, instead of character
- **ellipsis** - appended trailing suffix

-

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, limit = 25, completeWords = false, ellipsis = '...') {
    if (completeWords) {
      limit = value.substr(0, limit).lastIndexOf(' ');
    }
    return value.length > limit ? value.substr(0, limit) + ellipsis : value;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add a module entry.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TruncatePipe
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Usage**

Example String:

```
public longStr = 'A really long string that needs to be truncated';
```

Markup:

```
  <h1>{{longStr | truncate }}</h1> 
  <!-- Outputs: A really long string that... -->

  <h1>{{longStr | truncate : 12 }}</h1> 
  <!-- Outputs: A really lon... -->

  <h1>{{longStr | truncate : 12 : true }}</h1> 
  <!-- Outputs: A really... -->

  <h1>{{longStr | truncate : 12 : false : '***' }}</h1> 
  <!-- Outputs: A really lon*** -->
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a pipe, `limit = value.substr(0, 13).lastIndexOf(' ');` should be `limit = value.substr(0, limit).lastIndexOf(' ');` though.

Comment: You can also add something like that:
`if (!value) { return ''; }` and 
`if (value.length <= limit) { return value; }`

Comment: i had to add it to the export part of @ngModule as well to get it working. not sure why

Comment: @tibi its like a new component and you need to declare (declarations array) it in order to use it.

Comment: To avoid avoid appending ellipsis to unnecessary values add use ` if (value.length < limit) {
      return value;
    } else {
      return `${value.substr(0, limit)}${ellipsis}`;
    }`

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! But fails in two cases: (a) one word string (no space in string) and (b) one word string that exceeds limit. Returns in both cases only '...'

Comment: This still works. One might as well replace `substr` with `substring`

Answer (score 29):

You can truncate text based on CSS. It helps to truncate a text based on width not fix character.

Example

**CSS**

```css
.truncate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.content {
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="content">
    <span class="truncate">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
</div>
```

**Note: this code use full for one line not for more than one.**

**Ketan's Solution is best if you want to do it by Angular**

Comment: This. A thousand times this!

Comment: perfect for Accessibility

Answer (score 22):

Like this:

```js
{{ data.title | slice:0:20 }}
```

And if you want the ellipsis, here's a workaround

```js
{{ data.title | slice:0:20 }}...
```

Comment: Won't the three dots show up even when the `data.title` is not truncated?

Comment: Yes. This solution is assuming it will be always truncated

Comment: A more generic solution can be achieved if this worked for all kind of text truncated or not

Comment: Confirming this works well with Angular v11.

Comment: A solution to optionally append three dots `{{ data.title | slice:0:20 }}{{ data.title.length > 20 ? '...' : '' }}`

Answer (score 8):

### Limit length based on words

Try this one, if you want to truncate based on Words instead of characters while also allowing an option to see the complete text.

Came here searching for a **Read More** solution based on words, sharing the custom `Pipe` i ended up writing.

**Pipe:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'readMore'
})
export class ReadMorePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(text: any, length: number = 20, showAll: boolean = false, suffix: string = '...'): any {
    
    if (showAll) {
      return text;
    }

    if ( text.split(" ").length > length ) {
      
      return text.split(" ").splice(0, length).join(" ") + suffix;
    }

    return text;
  }

}
```

**In Template:**

```
<p [innerHTML]="description | readMore:30:showAll"></p>
<button (click)="triggerReadMore()" *ngIf="!showAll">Read More<button>
```

**Component:**

```
export class ExamplePage implements OnInit {

    public showAll: any = false;
    
    triggerReadMore() {
        this.showAll = true;
    }
    
}
```

**In Module:**

```
import { ReadMorePipe } from '../_helpers/read-more.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ReadMorePipe]
})
export class ExamplePageModule {}
```

Comment: Any idea how can I run it inside ngFor loop. It look like it when click on read more all the loop content visible at once.

Comment: @Santosh you can may be update triggerReadMore() function to specifically target the node by using parent or sibling relationships

Comment: Still the variable is global. it will not work. I however created an object and store each id with boolean value. It worked. Thank you for your response anyway. :)

Comment: Glad that you worked it out. You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach using an `interface` to describe the shape of an options object to be passed via the `pipe` in the markup.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'textContentTruncate'
})
export class TextContentTruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(textContent: string, options: TextTruncateOptions): string {
    if (textContent.length >= options.sliceEnd) {
      let truncatedText = textContent.slice(options.sliceStart, options.sliceEnd);
      if (options.prepend) { truncatedText = `${options.prepend}${truncatedText}`; }
      if (options.append) { truncatedText = `${truncatedText}${options.append}`; }
      return truncatedText;
    }
    return textContent;
  }

}

interface TextTruncateOptions {
  sliceStart: number;
  sliceEnd: number;
  prepend?: string;
  append?: string;
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
{{someText | textContentTruncate:{sliceStart: 0, sliceEnd: 50, append: '...'} }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Very simple using slice pipe (angular's core pipe), as you asked for `data.title`:

```
{{ data.title | slice:0:20 }}
```

From Angular common docs https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 5):

**Truncate String with Ellipsis**

No need any additional pipe, you can use slice.

```js
{{ stringText | slice: 0:25}} {{ stringText.length > 25 ? '...' : ''}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been using this module [ng2 truncate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-truncate), its pretty easy, import module and u are ready to go... in {{ data.title | truncate : 20 }}

Comment: it is move to here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yellowspot/ng-truncate

Comment: my tests failed after importing this. jest had some wired errors.

Comment: @tibi what kind of errors? for me it was very simple, install > import in module > use in its components..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truncate by a **number of words** and add an ellipsis you can use this function:

```js
truncate(value: string, limit: number = 40, trail: String = '…'): string {
  let result = value || '';

  if (value) {
    const words = value.split(/\s+/);
    if (words.length > Math.abs(limit)) {
      if (limit < 0) {
        limit *= -1;
        result = trail + words.slice(words.length - limit, words.length).join(' ');
      } else {
        result = words.slice(0, limit).join(' ') + trail;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Example:

```js
truncate('Bacon ipsum dolor amet sirloin tri-tip swine', 5, '…')
> "Bacon ipsum dolor amet sirloin…"
```

*taken from:
https://github.com/yellowspot/ng2-truncate/blob/master/src/truncate-words.pipe.ts*

If you want to truncate by a **number of letters** but don't cut words out use this:

```js
truncate(value: string, limit = 25, completeWords = true, ellipsis = '…') {
  let lastindex = limit;
  if (completeWords) {
    lastindex = value.substr(0, limit).lastIndexOf(' ');
  }
  return `${value.substr(0, limit)}${ellipsis}`;
}
```

Example:

```js
truncate('Bacon ipsum dolor amet sirloin tri-tip swine', 19, true, '…')
> "Bacon ipsum dolor…"

truncate('Bacon ipsum dolor amet sirloin tri-tip swine', 19, false, '…')
> "Bacon ipsum dolor a…"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried @Timothy Perez  answer and added a line

```
if (value.length < limit)
   return `${value.substr(0, limit)}`;
```

to

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(value: string, limit = 25, completeWords = false, ellipsis = '...') {

   if (value.length < limit)
   return `${value.substr(0, limit)}`;

   if (completeWords) {
     limit = value.substr(0, limit).lastIndexOf(' ');
   }
   return `${value.substr(0, limit)}${ellipsis}`;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate',
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, limit: number, trail = '...'): string {
    if (value.length <= limit) {
      return value;
    }

    return value.substring(0, limit - trail.length).replace(/\s+$/, '') + trail;
  }
}
```

```js
{{ str | truncate: 20 }}
{{ str | truncate: 20:'>>>'] }}
```

---

If you need truncate by words:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncateByWords',
})
export class TruncateByWordsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, limit: number, trail = '...'): string {
    if (value.length <= limit) {
      return value;
    }

    const substr = value.substring(0, limit - trail.length).split(' ');
    const isLastWordFull = value
      .split(' ')
      .find(w => w === substr[substr.length - 1]);

    if (isLastWordFull) {
      return substr.join(' ') + trail;
    }

    return substr.slice(0, -1).join(' ') + trail;
  }
}
```

```js
{{ str | truncateByWords: 20 }}
{{ str | truncateByWords: 20:'>>>'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more flexibilities if we want to truncate from the end or the start (based on @Nika Kasradze) :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
    const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[1], 10) : 20;
    const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[3] : '...';
    return value.length > limit ? (args[2] === 'start' ? trail : '') + value.substr(args[0], limit) + (args[2] === 'end' ? trail : '') : value;
   }
}
```

How to use ?

```
{{ myLongText | truncate:[20, myLongText.length-20, 'start', '...'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
    name: 'truncate',
    standalone: true,
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, limit = 10): string {
        if(!value) return ''
        const trail = '...'
        return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value
    }
}
```