# How to truncate HTML content in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have used one pipe to truncate ,Working fine with normal text but not in html content

**app.html**

```
  <tr>
  <td>{{howtoreach?.content|truncate :40}}</td>  //html content.not working
  <td>{{howtoreach?.id}}</td>                   //Working
  <td>
```

[image: howtoreach]

Comment: what is `howtoreach`?

Comment: @Maximus HTML content ,Qn Updated

Comment: no, how do you get it in the template?

Comment: If `howtoreach.content` is an HTML string, then truncating it is not going to work very well. It will probably truncate it in the middle of a tag. In any case, you'll need to insert it using `[innerHTML]`

Comment: Any other way to make it dynamically aligned?

Comment: This may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669340/how-to-truncate-text-in-angular2/44669515#44669515

Comment: 1. you shouldn't be adding HTML in this manner in angular application 2. it doesn't make sense to truncate an HTML string

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and realised that it was difficult to find an Angular 2 solution with `innerHTML`.

### My solution

You could create a custom function like this:

```
truncateHTML(text: string): string {

    let charlimit = 160;
    if(!text || text.length <= charlimit )
    {
        return text;
    }


  let without_html = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
  let shortened = without_html.substring(0, charlimit) + "...";
  return shortened;
}
```

And then in your view:

`<div [innerHTML]="truncateHTML(html_string)"></div>`

That should work.

---

**Last comment**

*I'm using `innerHTML` because there is still a bunch of unformatted characters like:*

```
&oslash; &aelig; &nbsp;
```

*Especially if you're from a nordic country with æ, ø and å :)*

---

Regex is from: [StripHTML post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript).

### Update

I had to replace breaks `<br />` before replacing HTML, so the word at the end of a line (before a line break) and the next (first word on line) had space in between them when shown:

```
let adding_spaces = text.replace(/<br \/>/g, "&nbsp;");
```