# Bootstrap card-text Limit to four lines

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I have following line of HTML codes and I would like to show or display only four lines of description in each card and rest text would display when I click on "readmore" button, which probably render in different page/pages. Therefore how to limit the lines or characters in card-text in bootstrap. Help is appreciated:-

```
 <div class="col-4 ml-2" *ngFor="let t of techBlogs">
                <div class="card shadow">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{t.title}}</h2>
                    <h4 class="card-text">{{t.name}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="card-text text-muted" id="run">{{t.postCreatedDate | date}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="card-text">Description: {{t.description}}
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">read more..</a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the text to number of lines may not be the best way to go about this. Bootstrap is responsive and will show a different number of lines depending on the size of the device, so you can't rely on it as a measurement.

If you are able to use wordcount instead, [this SO answer has examples of creating a truncation filter and applying it in your markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669340/how-to-truncate-text-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

Set `line-height` in rem, then set `height = number of lines * line-height`